# mongoose model.findOne is not a function (Node.js | React Native)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, react-native, mongoose

So, I am making an app with react native and i am trying to use mongoose and mongoDB for my DataBase but i am running into this error: **OD.findOne is not a function**, OD being my model file.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const newOrgData = new mongoose.Schema({
author: String,
PW: String,
name: String,
Good: Number,
Bad: Number,
Medium: Number
});
module.exports = new mongoose.model("OrganizationData", newOrgData)
```

My DB.js file where i do the function:

```
const OD = require("../config/OrgData");
export async function GetStats(txt, point) {
await OD.findOne({
    name: txt
}, (err, data) => {
    if (txt.length <= 3) return Alert.alert("Please use a valid organization, the name needs to be over three characters long.");
    if (err) console.log(err);
    if (!data) {
        Alert.alert("Sorry, that organization does not exist.");
        return;
    } else {
        if (point == 1) {
            data.Good++;
            data.save();
        } else {
            if (point == 2) {
                data.bad++;
                data.save();
            } else {
                if (point == 3) {
                    data.medium++;
                    data.save();
                } else {
                    if (point == 0) {
                        return Alert.alert("Please choose how you feel about this organization today.");
                    } else {
                        Alert.alert("Succes, thank you for your interest.");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
}
```

My server.js file where i connect to mongoose:

```
const Config = require("./config/config.json");

const mongoose = require("mongoose");

mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://BlueSyntax:" + Config.Mongo_C_PW + 
"@org-qjoao.mongodb.net/" + Config.DB_Name + "?retryWrites=true&w=majority", {
useMongoClient: true
});
```

How should i fix this?

Comment: Change module.exports = new mongoose.model("OrganizationData", newOrgData) to module.exports = mongoose.model("OrganizationData", newOrgData). The "new" keyword is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You have to omit `new` keyword when exporting the model. The correct form:

```js
module.exports = mongoose.model("OrganizationData", newOrgData)
```

Comment: Thanks :) I will try that!

Comment: That did not help :(